# extending TriggeringEventEvaluator (log4j) and supplying properties for it in config

Tags: java, email, logging, smtp, log4j

this interface is used by SMTPAppender class in log4j. 
It has a method which returns a status (if to trigger an email alert or not)

The problem is that 
i want to add somefunctionality to TriggeringEventEvaluator.
this requires some extra fields to specify in config for TriggeringEventEvaluator.

How can I pass these fields from log4j config to TriggeringEventEvaluator.
I know that log4j calls setter methods for fields but how can fields be specified for TriggeringEventEvaluator

Comment: I think this answer here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931650/log4j-xml-injecting-evaluator/34989591#34989591

Answer (score 1):

Define a TriggeringPolicy element inside the SMTPAppender element.  The TriggeringPolicy element's class would be org.apache.log4j.rolling.FilterBasedTriggeringPolicy.

Inside the TriggeringPolicy element, define a 'filter' element whose class is org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter.

You can then use any event field you want (and regexp support using the 'like' keyword) in order to filter events.  The developer snapshot of Chainsaw has a pretty good tutorial on the expression syntax: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Example:

```
<appender name="mail" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
  <param name="from"   value="[EMAIL PROTECTED]" />
  <param name="to" value="[EMAIL PROTECTED]" />
  <param name="subject" value="Test message" />
  <param name="SMTPHost" value="localhost"/>
  <param name="sendOnClose" value="true"/>
  <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.FilterBasedTriggeringPolicy">
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
      <param name="Expression" value="( LOGGER ~= class1 &amp;&amp; MSG ~= test1 ) || ( logger ~= class2 &amp;&amp; MSG like 'TEST2' )"/>
    </filter>
  </triggeringPolicy>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: can u explain a little more..
 what I want to accomplish is that I want to set a max email limit that can be sent in a time interval. So max email limit and time frame should be specified in log4j config. And triggering evaluator should decide based on these parameters if it is ok to send mail or not. if limit for sending mail has been exceeded, triggeringevaluator should return false. 
is similar behaviour can be accomplished with triggering Policy, please help with little more explanation.

Comment: Triggering policies can't be set in the properties file format I believe, just the xml format.

You can write a custom TriggeringPolicy (which implements TriggeringEventEvaluator) which tracks whatever you want in the isTriggeringEvent implementation, returning true when appropriate (based on time, logging event count, etc).