# Log4j.xml injecting Evaluator

Tags: java, logging, log4j

My project is using log4j 1.2.17. I have successfully injected my custom "Evaluator" into the SMTPAppender, using [setEvaluatorClass](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html#setEvaluatorClass(java.lang.String)) :

```
<appender name="email" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
  <param name="EvaluatorClass" value="path.to.my.Evaluator" />
```

However, I would like to pass some params to my Evaluator, to make it configurable. I would like to use [SMTPAppender.setEvaluator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html#SMTPAppender(org.apache.log4j.spi.TriggeringEventEvaluator)), but I cannot figure out how to set that up in log4j.xml. Another option would be [the other SMTPAppender constructor](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html#SMTPAppender(org.apache.log4j.spi.TriggeringEventEvaluator)), which I have also been unsuccessful in using via log4j.xml

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [API doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html) of SMTPAppender:

> The triggering criteria can be modified by setting the evaluatorClass
>   property with the name of a class implementing
>   TriggeringEventEvaluator, setting the evaluator property with an
>   instance of TriggeringEventEvaluator or nesting a triggeringPolicy
>   element where the specified class implements TriggeringEventEvaluator.

Basically, I can use a nested triggeringPolicy element to emulate the behavior of an evaluator. The added advantage is that, I can pass arguments to the triggeringPolicy element.

I had a use case of sending email digest for every n - messages. For that I used the following TriggeringPolicy:

```
package org.email;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.TriggeringEventEvaluator;


public class MyEvaluator implements TriggeringEventEvaluator {

    private volatile int num = 1;

    private int quotient = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(LoggingEvent event) {
        return num++ % quotient == 0;
    }

    public void setQuotient(int quotient) {
        this.quotient = quotient;
    }
}
```

My log4j.xml configuration, which sends one mail for every two log events is given below:

```
<appender name="ErrorEmailAppender"     class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
    <param name="SMTPHost" value="myHost" />
    <param name="From" value="xxxxx@yyy.com" />
    <param name="To" value="xxxxx@yyy.com" />
    <param name="Subject" value="Log of messages" />
    <triggeringPolicy class="org.email.MyEvaluator">
        <param name="quotient" value="2" />
   </triggeringPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Hope this helps!